# Template dependent implementation

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a simple piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template<typename T>
class A {
    public:
        T _v;
        template<unsigned short V> void init() { _v *= V; }
        void print(double txt) { std::cout << "Initialized with ?? : " << txt << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    A<double> foo;
    foo._v = 3.5;
    foo.init<2>();
    foo.print(foo._v);

    A<int> bar;
    bar._v = 2;
    bar.init<5>();
    foo.print(bar._v);
}
```

I would like to have an implementation of the function `A::print(double)` dependent on the `unsigned short V`, for example, replace `??` by the `unsigned short` from which `init()` has been instanciated. My questions are: (a) is it doable ? (b) if (a), how ?

While searching if (a), I thought I could add a functor to the `class A<T>`, initialize its state (with the value of `V`) in `init()`, call it in `print(double)`, but I have never used such objects so I have no idea if this is the way to go. I'm basically open to any suggestions, the only thing I need is that the call to `print` remains the same (because I'll call it from other classes who have no idea of the value of `unsigned short V`.

Thanks !

Comment: There's `typeid(txt).name()`, but it's going to differ from compiler to compiler.

Comment: I want the output to be : "Initialized with 2 : 7, Initialized with 5 : 10", not the type of `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    public:
        T _v;
        unsigned short _v2;
        template<unsigned short V> void init() { _v2 = V;  _v *= V; }
        void print(double txt) { std::cout << "Initialized with "
            << _v2 << " : " << txt << std::endl; }
};
```

Or why not:

```
template<typename T, unsigned short V>
struct A {
        T _v = V;
        void print(double txt) { std::cout << "Initialized with "
            << V << " : " << txt << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: Oh man I feel stupid.. Is `_v2` set at compile time ? (i.e. if I were to use a bool instead of a `unsigned short`, would all conditional statements based on `_v2` evaluated at compile time or run time ?)

Comment: In the first version it is set at runtime.  In the second version it is set at compile time.

Comment: I cannot use option 2, because when I create `foo` and `bar`, I don't know a priori the value of `V`. Is there anyway to set the behavior of `print` at compile time without the extra template for `A` ?

Comment: No, because what if someone calls print before calling init.  Where should print get the value of V from at compile time in this case?